# CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing when using ScrollView (and NestedScrollView)

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-coordinatorlayout

I´m trying to use CollapsingToolbarLayout with a ScrollView but I do not get it to work. I try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:behavior_overlapTop="192dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:padding="@dimen/medium_padding"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent">

                          <!-- my content -->


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/fondo_drawer"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:minHeight="100dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I tested with ScrollView and NestedScrollView unsuccessfully.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i think

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" is the cause.
```

check about my simple working example code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/product_detail_main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:apptools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/product_detail_appBar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_product_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom|right"
            android:foregroundTintMode="add"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/space_xxlarge"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/image"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/product_toolBar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
              app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
           app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
 ........
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

you can check this link http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: Yeah!! your example work fine. I think I needed to introduce all within CoordinatorLayout!. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same mistake `abhishek's` answer is perfect.

I want to add little bit. If you do `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` only for AppBarLayout it will work, you don't have to set it for `ImageView` and `ToolBar` - since they are part of `AppBarLayout` and this will be applicable for them as well.

Have a look here - https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.an1hvz44l

> System windows are the parts of the screen where the system is drawing
>   either non-interactive (in the case of the status bar) or interactive
>   (in the case of the navigation bar) content.
>
> Most of the time, your app won’t need to draw under the status bar or
>   the navigation bar, but if you do: you need to make sure interactive
>   elements (like buttons) aren’t hidden underneath them. That’s what the
>   default behavior of the android:fitsSystemWindows=“true” attribute
>   gives you: it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents
>   don’t overlay the system windows.